# DataFrame object has extra methods after importing package ffn

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As we know, `DataFrame` initially has no methods like `rebase`,`to_return`. If you code as below

> import pandas as pd
>   import numpy as np
>   df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,2),index=pd.date_range("2010-01-01",periods=100))
>   df.rebase()

It will return:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'rebase'

However, once you import `ffn`(this is a finance package which you can install with command `pip install ffn`),  then everything is fine.

> import ffn
>   df.rebase()

This will return:

> 2010-01-01  100.000000  100.000000
>   2010-01-02   31.619524 -181.074423
>   2010-01-03  -56.407982   10.680311
>   2010-01-04  -26.719401 -175.153792
>   ...

WHY?
How comes that the DataFrame objects get those methods？
What is the mechanism?

I am using Python 3.6 on Anaconda, Mac OS 10.12.6.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because `import ffn` library adds [`extend_pandas`](https://github.com/pmorissette/ffn/blob/4670a22c0b992d34bb58fda9e82884e90fcc2931/ffn/core.py#L2060) function which, extends pandas' PandasObject (Series, DataFrame) with some functions.

Comment: Got it. You are right. From the MRO list
`pd.DataFrame.__mro__`
I found that DataFrame is the subclass of PandasObject, which is added some extra methods by the function `extend_pandas`.

Thanks very much!